# node.js socket.io catch connection to unavailable room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Can I create some listener for catching connections on room that not exist?

And what happens with requests which are sent on unavailable rooms?
Is it a way to d/dos?

Comment: please explain what a "room" is for your app. also how do users connect to rooms? and so on. explain more in detail and add some relevant code.

Comment: "room" I mean namespaces: var ns1 = io.of('/ns1')

Comment: is my question clear?